# Type unavailable in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I created a test project in Qt 6.4.2. This project includes two classes, TestClass1 and TestClass2. Now when I want to start the program it gives a weird error that the TestClass1 is unavailable (***qrc:/testTypeProject/main.qml:11:5: Type TestClass1 unavailable***). Please advise if possible.

[TestClass1 and TestClass2 and its error in QtCreator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osEb8.png)

TestClass1.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: root

    property int counter: 0

    property TestClass2 testClass2: TestClass2 {
        testClass1: root
    }
}
```

TestClass2.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml
import QtQuick.Controls

Item {

    //! Handle TestClass1 in TestClass2
    property TestClass1 testClass1

    property Timer _timer: Timer {
        repeat: true
        running: true
        interval: 1000
        onTriggered: {
         testClass1.counter++;
            console.debug("testClass1.counter = ", testClass1.counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import QtQuick.Controls

    Window {
        width: 640
        height: 480
        visible: true
        title: qsTr("Hello World")
    
        property TestClass1 testClass1: TestClass1 {
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your original code you have some strange `import testTypeProject` that probably cause to error and so import fails. That besides the strange approach to store pointer to the parent, you always can use `ObjectId.parent` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nasty cyclic dependency happening. One way to break the cyclic dependency you can make the following changes:

- Change the property type from `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` to the `var` type
- Do not declare instances in their definition, instead
- Declare instances in the main application and wire them up in the main application

Here's a demo:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    TestClass1 {
        id: appTestClass1
        testClass2: appTestClass2
    }
    TestClass2 {
        id: appTestClass2
        testClass1: appTestClass1
    }
    Frame {
        Text {
            text: appTestClass1.counter
        }
    }
}

// TestClass1.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Item {
    property int counter: 0
    property var testClass2
}

// TestClass2.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Item {
    property var testClass1
    property Timer _timer: Timer {
        repeat: true
        running: true
        interval: 1000
        onTriggered: {
            testClass1.counter++;
            console.debug("testClass1.counter = ", testClass1.counter);
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAC+HicpZExa8MwEIV3/4ojU0qKY3t06BQIdEvAe1Gdw4jakno+hZTi/167UW1LTrtUi7h3p++hd7IxmhhOfLKyfIukV8Z7rZh03UZHUSF8RtCfAlve16JtUycMR55zEMZMvbHDP1LmT2TfE52PzP5AZktkes/0hjyQaHBGK/DKs/KGuXIAiEttFSONc51DdlG03c6+Hr83dRDWr9k9MzbO2pA2SPwBUjE4rxwSv3cRNEsttM7+a+3hU79XyAYJXni4cldNoREaFH1kTBYn0SolVRWocvjZRdQ5pEmSjLJWBcmqQsJ+ueE2wiVsNjtvotSq1TXGZ3y11Xq1fABPsHq8A3rYLff5BcQp5Ps=)